# Self enumerating function

Tags: ruby, enumeration

I've got some code:

```
def my_each_with_index
  return enum_for(:my_each_with_index) unless block_given?
  i = 0
  self.my_each do |x| 
    yield x, i 
    i += 1
  end
  self
end
```

It is my own code, but the line:

```
return enum_for(:my_each_with_index) unless block_given?
```

is found in solutions of other's. I can't get why they passed the function to `enum_for` as a parameter. When I invoke my function without a block, it won't return anything with or without `enum_for`. I could left sth like:

```
return unless block_given?
```

and it has the same result. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Being called without a block, it will return an enumerator:

```
▶ def my_each_with_index
▷   return enum_for(:my_each_with_index) unless block_given?  
▷ end  
#⇒ :my_each_with_index
▶ e = my_each_with_index
#⇒ #<Enumerator: main:my_each_with_index>
```

later on you might iterate on this enumerator:

```
▶ e.each { |elem| ... }
```

This behavior is specifically useful in some cases, like lazy iteration, passing block to this enumerator later etc.

Just returning `nil` cuts this ability off.

Comment: Think you! For now, I can't imagine where is it useful but I'm low experienced in ruby. I understand your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Think you for very precise answer. I recived also very good example to understand this issue for other new developers:

```
def iterator
yield 1
yield 2
yield 3
puts "koniec"
end

iterator { |v| puts v }
it = enum_for(:iterator)
puts it.next
puts it.next
puts it.next
puts it.next
```

Just run and analyze this code.

Answer (score 0):

For any method that accepts a block, a good method implementation should have a well-defined behavior when the block is not given.

In the example shared by you, `each_for_index` is being re-implemented by author, may be to provide additional semantics or may be just for academic purpose given that its behavior is same as Ruby's [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

The documentation has following for [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

> Calls block with two arguments, the item and its index, for each item
>   in enum. Given arguments are passed through to each().
>
> **If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.**

In order to stay consistent with highlighted line indicating what should be the behavior if block is not given, one has to use something like

```
return enum_for(:my_each_with_index) unless block_given?
```

[`enum_for`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/enum_for) is interesting method

> `enum_for` creates a new Enumerator which will enumerate by calling `method` on `obj`.

Below is an example reproduced from documentation:

```
str = "xyz"

enum = str.enum_for(:each_byte)
enum.each { |b| puts b }
# => 120
# => 121
# => 122
```

So, if one does not pass block to `my_each_with_index`, they have a chance to pass it later - just like one would have done with `each_with_index`.

```
e = obj.my_each_with_index
...
e.each { |x, i| # do something }  # `my_each_with_index` executed later
```

In summary, `my_each_with_index` tries to be consistent with `each_with_index` and tries to be a well-behaved API.